# wp-cli resetea la configuración de mi tema cuando ejecuto cualquier acción

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

He estado jugando un poco con [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) y me pasa que cuando ejecuto cualquier acción, ya sea activar o desactivar un plugin o lo que sea, se resetea la configuración de mi tema.

El tema que uso es uno [escrito por mi](https://github.com/rogertm/twenty-em), en el que guardo la configuración en un registro en la tabla `wp_options` llamado `t_em_theme_options`. El punto es que no borra el registro ni otra cosa, sino que lo deja con la configuración que debe cargar por defecto.

¿Alguien ha tenido alguna experiencia similar con wp-cli?

Aclaro que esto me pasa en `localhost`, no lo he probado en un servidor online.

Saludos y gracias de antemano...

Comment: Yo he usado mucho `wp-cli` y no he tenido esos problemas. Por favor, dinos las versiones que estas usando, tanto de PHP, como de `wp-cli`, Wordpress...etc

Comment: Bueno, estoy usando WordPress 4.8, PHP 7.0.18, SO Ubuntu 16.04.1, wp-cli 1.2.1...

Realmente no encuentro una explicación lógica, lo último que hice en mi theme fue añadir soporte para `starter-content`, comenté la linea y siguió el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré el problema y pude darle solución, el asunto es que tengo [una función](https://github.com/rogertm/twenty-em/blob/master/engine/theme-options.php#L142), que en caso de que el registro donde se guarda toda la configuración no esté accesible o vacía, esta se restaura con las opciones por defecto. El problema estaba dado a que esta función estaba enganchada al hook `after_setup_theme`, ahora la enganché a `wp` y todo marcha bien.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Saludos...